# 2D dynamicly allocated array in c and freeing them

Tags: c

I need to make a global alignment for sequences in C.
For that, I made a 2D dynamically allocated array that way:

```
Cell **matrix;
matrix = (Cell **)malloc(rows * sizeof(Cell *));
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    matrix[r] = (Cell *) malloc(columns * sizeof(Cell));
}
```

`Cell` represents a single table in the great table, `rows` is the length of one sequence and `columns` is the length of the second.

After making the first iteration, the whole getting mass because of problem with freeing the data.

I made the `free` in the traditional way:

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    free(matrix[r]);
    matrix[r] = NULL;
}
free(matrix);
```

Assigning `NULL` to matrix doesn't do anything.

Any advices?

Comment: "assigning NULL to matrix doesn't do a thing." what should it do? Code looks valid and works fine for me.

Comment: when I insert data to the matrix problems come.Any idea why would it happen ?

Comment: What problems? Also what is `Cell`? Maybe the issue is how you fill the array? EDIT: I should say that i substituted your `Cell` type?/struct? with `int` so your `Cell` might be the problem

Comment: Also it is very unclear what your actual question is. Neither in the title nor in the body you ask anything precise.

Comment: typedef struct Cell
{
    int value;
    struct Cell *prev;
}Cell;

cell is just the type which I use ...

Comment: I would guess that perhaps the problem lies in how you are accessing (reading/writing) individual members of the matrix. Can you edit the question and include the code that's misbehaving? (As an aside, I worry when I see `struct Cell *prev` in the structure because that implies you're using a list rather than a 2D array to manage the `Cell` objects, so maybe something is going wrong there?.)

Comment: The above example is all right. As you have not provided the code to fill the array i assume the error is somewhere there and has propably something to do with your `struct Cell *prev` member. How do you manage those in a 2D array? By column? Usually this is the structure of a linked list which is one dimensional.